# JavaScript Callback Functions.. confused

Tags: javascript, function, callback, gulp

I'm sure the answer to this question exists somewhere, but unsure how to phrase the question and don't find what I'm looking for when I try to research callbacks.

Ok, so I've just started dabbling with Gulp for compiling my CSS, and I think it's great!.. despite being useless with JavaScript.

My code is below, but I don't understand how these callbacks are working. How can callbacks be set as a parameter and then be called from inside the function? I don't get it.. is the function basically expecting something to be in there? What value is being set or what's expected to run? I can't seem to make sense of it.

I see this quite frequently in JavaScript, but unsure how it works. I've looked up videos and tutorials of functions and callbacks, they makes sense, but I never seem to be able to find anywhere where this concept is explained which makes me believe I'm not looking for the right thing.

I see the same sort of thing with Promises as well where 'resolve' or 'reject' parameters are set, but unsure what's going on when a condition is met, or what values are set and where.. hope this makes sense and appreciate any help in understanding this better.

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');


// TASKS
// Compile SASS
gulp.task('sass-compile', (callback) => {
    gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    console.log('******************** SCSS > CSS successful ********************');
    callback();
});

// Live reload
gulp.task('browser-sync', (callback) => {  
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: 'http://localhost/test1',
        port: 80
    });
    callback();
});

// WATCHER
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('browser-sync', (callback) => {
    gulp.watch('scss/*.scss', gulp.series('sass-compile'));
    callback();
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function foo(baz) {
  console.log("Foo: " + baz);
}

function other(bar) {
    const arg = "Bar";
    bar(arg);
}

other(foo);
```

I can see how this is useful when it comes to performing asynchronous tasks. But its quite counter intuitive and I can immediately see the potential for type errors.

I've since changed my coding style to use ASYNC/AWAIT instead as much as possible. But it still a pain to navigate legacy code. Hence, the reason why I ended up looking up this thread. Haha

Answer (score -1):

Functions are a type of object. Objects are a type of value.

Values can be stored in variables, in object properties, and passed as arguments to functions.

So:

Here is a simple function, which is called.

```js
function foo() {
  console.log("Foo");
}

foo();
```

Here is a simple function, copied to a different variable, which is called.

```js
function foo() {
  console.log("Foo");
}

const bar = foo;

bar();
```

And now passed as an argument to another function.

```js
function foo() {
  console.log("Foo");
}

function other(bar) {
    bar();
}

other(foo);
```

And the same, but with arguments passed to the original function.

```js
function foo(baz) {
  console.log("Foo: " + baz);
}

function other(bar) {
    const arg = "Bar";
    bar(arg);
}

other(foo);
```

You've just been looking at examples where the function responsible for calling the callback is not code you've written (and you aren't looking at the source code of the function which calls the callback).

Answer (score -1):

In javascript, functions are first class objects, which means they can be passed around to other functions. There are many cases where this can be used, but the cases you're referring to (gulp.task and new Promise) are essentially using it to do two-way communication between your code and their code. When you use gulp.task, basically the following steps are happening

1) You call gulp.task, saying "i'd like to do some work please". You pass in a function saying what you'd like to do
2) at the appropriate time, gulp.task calls your function, but passes in to it another function saying "when you're done, call this to let me know".

A simplified version of gulp.task would look like this:

```js
const task = (name, workToDo) => {
  const done = () => {
    console.log('task', name, 'has let me know its done');
  }
  
  console.log('ive been asked to start task', name);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('500ms elapsed; starting task', name);
    workToDo(done);    
  }, 500);
}

task('sample', (done) => {
 console.log('doing work');
 setTimeout(() => {
   console.log('1 second has elapsed. calling back to let it know i am done');
   done();
 }, 1000)
});
```

The constructor for a promise has a similar purpose. You say "i'd like to create a promise, using the following code", and then it calls your code passing in two functions that it just created (usually named `resolve` and `reject`). These are used to tell the promise "i'm done successfully" or "i'm done with an error", and thus move the promise to a resolved state or a rejected state.